# вспоминаешь или Помнишь?

Tags: грамматика, лексикон

**Вспоминаешь** или **Помнишь**?
What is the difference between these?
Both mean remember(singular-informal) but two different faces!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> — Помнишь Иванова?
>   — Иванова? А, вспоминаю (вспомнил).

*Помнить* is to remember, to keep in mind. It is a state.

*Вспоминать (вспомнить)* is to recall, to bring memories back. It is an action, a process, when memories come back.

Comment: It's not clear to me! remember and recall both have the same meaning!

Comment: Ok, is there any difference between "keep in mind " which is a state and "bring memories back", which is an action?

Answer (score 1):

Only **`помнишь`** means **`remember`**

**`вспоминаешь`** means **`recall, recollect, reminisce`**

Comment: It's not clear to me! remember and recall both have the same meaning!

Comment: @WorldLover they do not, i'm not aware of your native tongue which might have the same word for both, but not Russian or English, there's semantic difference between **to keep in mind/to store information in the memory** (remember) and **to bring to mind** (recall), you only can **recall** what you already **remember**, **remembrance** is taking information in and keeping it in the memory, **recollection** is retrieval of information from the memory